# Why does this method repeats its loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

This method retrieves and validates a social security number from the user. It works fine if the input is valid. If not, `while (true)` repeats instead of going to the

```
else {
    System.out.println("Make sure the social security number is valid.");
}
```

statement.

Here is the method:

```
public static String getSSN(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
        String ssn = "";

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(prompt);
            if(sc.hasNext()) {
                ssn = sc.next();
                if(ssn.length() == 11 
                    && checkNumeric(ssn.substring(0, 3)) 
                    && "-".equalsIgnoreCase(ssn.substring(3, 4))
                    && checkNumeric(ssn.substring(4, 6)) 
                    && "-".equalsIgnoreCase(ssn.substring(6, 7)) 
                    && checkNumeric(ssn.substring(7, 11)))
                    break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Make sure the social security number is valid.");
            }
        }
        return ssn;       
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter a Social Security Number: 
23
Enter a Social Security Number: 
4
Enter a Social Security Number: 
2
```

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted.

Comment: Check your curly brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bracketing is incorrect. The `else` branch belongs to `if(sc.hasNext())` condition. To make the code work, move it to the appropriate place :

```
public static String getSSN(Scanner sc, String prompt) {
    String ssn = "";

    while (true) {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        if(sc.hasNext()) {
            ssn = sc.next();
            if(ssn.length() == 11 
                && checkNumeric(ssn.substring(0, 3)) 
                && "-".equalsIgnoreCase(ssn.substring(3, 4))
                && checkNumeric(ssn.substring(4, 6)) 
                && "-".equalsIgnoreCase(ssn.substring(6, 7)) 
                && checkNumeric(ssn.substring(7, 11))) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Make sure the social security number is valid.");
            }
        }            
    }
    return ssn;       
}
```

It's considered a good habit to wrap the one line statements in braces also. It makes the code cleaner and also less error prone if the branch changes and another commands are added.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have done something like:

```
while(sc.hasNext()) ...
```